# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [obj Undefined]

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

**Error**: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [obj Undefined]

Here, the endpoints will be '**/EmpDeleteAll**'

Index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("./models");

const app = express();

const EmpFunction = require('./controllers/emp.controller')();

const functions = [
  { name: "Emp", function: EmpFunction }
];


app.use(cors({
  origin: '*',
  methods: 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT',
  allowedHeaders: 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept'
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to HR application API" });
});

functions.forEach(func => {
  const { name, function: funcObject } = func;

  app.post(`/${name}DeleteAll`, funcObject.deleteAll);
});


db.mongoose.connect(db.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to the database!");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Cannot connect to the database!", err);
    process.exit();
});
```

emp.controller.js

```
const db = require("../models");
const Employee = db.employee;
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require('cors')

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
  

// Delete all Employees
exports.deleteAll = (req, res) => {
    Employee.deleteMany({})
    .then(data => {
      res.send({
        message: `${data.deletedCount} Employees were deleted successfully!`
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while removing all Employees."
      });
    });
};

module.exports = router;
```

Dont know Why m receving above error, I guess doing something wrong with router, may be I need to assign response value to it, but dont know how ?

Can you please help findout cause and solution for above error ? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove Router part, from **emp.controllers.js** file,

Next, add below line at the end of **Index.js**

```
const firebase = require("firebase-functions");
exports.app = firebase.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: This is not the answer user looking for !

Comment: HI I tried and project run, getting this The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code: EmpDeleteAll(us-central1)